# Logitech g930 headset

Tags: c#, winforms, logitech

I have a Logitech G930 headset - it is wireless, and has HotKeys on the headset itself. I am looking to have one of the HotKeys let me answer a Skype call when it comes in.

Where should I start? There is an API for the headset, and also an API for Skype - but I am wondering if it would just be easier to use Spy++ to find the the Skype 'answer button' on the 'incoming call' dialog which is always on top? Any advice on how to accomplish this - with basic knowledge in C#?

I am using Windows 7 Home 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how it is implemented. Perhaps it doesn't use Win32 messages and so Spy++ won't help you. The best bet is to rely on the API abstractions, since the underlying implementation is subject to change.